# How to read integers and date in binary file

Tags: java, binary

I have a binary file of records. Each record is of the following format:
Each record consists of two integers, number of vehicles and number of persons involved; a floating point number, severity code; and a string which contains the date of the accident. This date takes the following form: a three letter month abbreviation followed by a space, then a day of the month followed by a comma, and finally the year which may be represented by a two digit or four digit number.

Following is the code.But I am not getting the proper answer..

my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class BoydBAssignment5_Ver1 {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        DataInputStream input1;                     //you need these two variable for a file
        File            infile1;
        input1 = null;

        BoydBAssignment5_Ver1 tfr;                  //this is your program object
        tfr = new BoydBAssignment5_Ver1();
        try{    //try for open
            infile1 = new File("assign5.data");
            input1 = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(infile1));
        } catch (IOException i){
            i.printStackTrace();}

        tfr.read_records(input1);
        try {   //try for close
            input1.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("error in close");
        }
    }

    private void read_records(DataInputStream is2) {
        int totalVehicles=0,totalPersons=0;
        int numVehicles;
        int numPeople;
        char ch;

        try {   //try for read
            while(true) {
                numVehicles=is2.readInt();
                if(numVehicles==0)
                break;

                totalVehicles+=numVehicles;
                System.out.print("\n"+numVehicles+"\t");
                numPeople=is2.readInt();
                if(numPeople==0)
                break;

                totalPersons+=numPeople;
                System.out.print(numPeople+"\t");
                System.out.print(is2.readDouble()+"\t");
                /*System.out.print(is2.readLine()+"\n");
                    for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
                    {
                        is2.readByte();
                    }*/
                while((ch=(char)is2.readByte()) != 0x00) {
                    System.out.print(ch+"");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\nTotal no of vehicles:"+totalVehicles);
            System.out.println("Total no of Persons:"+totalPersons);
            write_in_file(totalVehicles,totalPersons);
        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("error in write");
        }

    }

    private void write_in_file(int totalVehicles, int totalPersons) {
        try {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("finalOutput.data");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write("Number of vehicles involved"+"\t"+totalVehicles);
            out.write("\nNumber of persons involved"+"\t"+totalPersons);
            out.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output ::

> 148308        1        4.774904982E-314
>   189429102        540161068        1.4275957977117199E-71
>   512        576        6.903600071305329E-93         8,98
>   37966848        512        1.7668797952966E-311
>   Mar 4,2006
>   37966848        256        2.8513257442947E-311
>   Apr 8,2011
>   38683904        512        2.3101107177838E-311                Jun 14,06
>   38683904        256        6.792508527386E-312        Apr 22,2005
>   38683904        256        1.2216329768334E-311        Oct 1,04
>   38683904        768        2.3099515681247E-311        Jul 9,83
>   38813952        256        6.802588006634E-312        Aug 4. 1998
>   38813952        512        6.802588006634E-312        Jun 14, 2011
>   38813952        512        1.7667206456376E-311                Sep 8, 99
>   39344128
>   Total no of vehicles:576033218
>   Total no of Persons:540165485

Please help me..Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure that the integers are 32-bit? Additionally, the `readDouble` method will read 64 bytes of floating point information.

Comment: In your Output you have dates, but you don't read any in your code. Are you sure this code produces that output?

Comment: ya this given output is corresponding to the code and i have made the code 
while((ch=(char)is2.readByte()) != 0x00) {
                    System.out.print(ch+"");
}
for date reading as a string read.. Please if there is any other method then tell me..thnk you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

By guess is that you data is store as little-endian. `DataInputStream` is big-endian. (If you are not sure what endianness is see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

The simplest thing to do is to read the file into a single direct `ByteBuffer` which allows you to set the byte order.

Comment: Given that the second integer is '1', that wouldn't seem to be the case here; I suspect, since the date doesn't appear on some lines, that the byte sizes for the integers may be off.

Comment: thank you for this point...can you tell me how to convert big-endian to little-endian and vice-versa..
thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` and `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)`