# How to read Date from VB binary-file in another language?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I get a binary file from a VB-application which consists of about 1400 records of a Timestamp in Date format followed by 19 Long values.

I am able to read the data in VBA with this function:

```
Dim myDate As Date
Dim myLong As Long
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open "C:\test.bin" For Binary Access Read As #iFileNum
Do While Not EOF(iFileNum)
  Get iFileNum, , myDate
  MsgBox(myDate)
  For i = 1 To 19
    Get iFileNum, , myLong
  Next i
Loop
```

Now i want to read the Date-timestamps from the file (I am already able to read the Long-values) within java, but i cannot find any information on how to interpret the 8 bytes of the Date-type.

As an example, the first timestamp in binary form is `c5 b3 a2 11 80 7b e4 40`.
VB output for this is 2014-11-05 0:03:06 AM.

To clarify, I am not looking for a java implementation, but for information of the binary representation of data type 'Date' from VB.
(for which i wasn't able to find any more information as than this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx , which doesn't help much)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a code translation service

Comment: I am not lloking for a code-translation. But for a source on exact information about the Date data type.

Comment: You might want to add a `Java` tag to get help about Java. In the meantime, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555262/how-to-read-integers-and-date-in-binary-file). This question deals with binary to multiple data type conversion.

Comment: The Date datatype in VBA is stored as a DOUBLE (i.e., Double-Precision floating point) scaled to days: so 1.5 is the same as 1 and 1/2 days or 36 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RBarryYoung mentions in his comment to the question, VBA stores Date/Time values internally as floating-point `Double` values. The integer part is the number of days since 1899-12-30 and the fractional part is the time (e.g., 0.25 = 6 AM, 0.5 = Noon, 0.75 = 6 PM).

In the example you gave, the Date/Time (Double) value is stored in bytes as `c5 b3 a2 11 80 7b e4 40`. Windows has always been a little-endian environment, so by reversing the order of the bytes we know that it corresponds to the 64-bit binary value `0x40e47b8011a2b3c5`.

A Binary-to-IEEE_Double convertor like [this one](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=40E47B8011A2B3C5) tells us that the decimal `Double` value is `4.19480021527777789742685854435E4`, and if we ask VBA what the corresponding Date/Time value is we get

```
?CDate(41948.0021527777789742685854435)
2014-11-05 00:03:06
```