# How to read Date from VB binary-file in java

Tags: java, date, vb6, type-conversion

I Have a file produced by a visual basic program that I wrote years ago.  I am trying to convert this data so I can read it in a replacement java program I also wrote.  I am having problems converting the VB date which is an 8 byte double.  I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942748/how-to-read-date-from-vb-binary-file-in-another-language) thread.  By going through the steps, I am able to convert the date manually (0x00000000E080E440) (12/18/2014).  Little endian to big endian decimal = 4.1991E4, which 41991 represents the correct date.  Now I am trying to write this in java.  The other post references code for swapping and I have plucked this code:

```
/**
   * Byte swap a single double value.
   * 
   * @param value  Value to byte swap.
   * @return       Byte swapped representation.
   */
  public static double swap (double value)
  {
    long longValue = Double.doubleToLongBits (value);
    longValue = swap (longValue);
    return Double.longBitsToDouble (longValue);
  }
```

That code does not compile.  I am just learning java so bear with me.  This code looks like it is recursively calling itself, however when it calls itself (swap) it is passing longValue which is long when swap is expecting double.  Am I missing something?  How can I get the bytes swapped from little endian to big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not call itself. It is calling a method `swap(long longValue)`, and your method is `swap(double value`). It probably doesn't compile because you do not have the other method.

Comment: I get message, "Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to long.  The method swap will recurse infinitely."

Comment: The compiler is looking for a method `swap(long longvalue)`; since it does not find one, it assumes you want to convert the double to a long and call the routine you have. I repeat, there is probably a method to reverse the bytes for a long that you do not have in your code, and therefore this code is faulty, throws this compilation message, and will not work. Go back to where you plucked this code from and see if it doesn't have the missing method.